# Stopping listening to DOM events in Backbone

Tags: javascript, events, dom, backbone.js

Today I learned that the `listenTo` method of Backbone.View is intended for listening for events `trigger`-ed by changes in Backbone models or collections. It is not designed to listen to DOM events.

Which raises the following question. Backbone documentation says that when a Backbone view is `remove`-ed, it will automatically unsubscribe from all events that it was listening through `listenTo`. It does not specifically mention the fate of the listeners that the view placed on the DOM elements.

So what happens when a view listenining to DOM events is being removed? And is there any difference between the following two scenarios?

- a view has an `events` object that contains a list of events on the child nodes of the view’s `$el` that are being listened to;
- a view listens to some arbitrary DOM elements, not necessarily children of the view’s `$el`. is this situation any different from the previous one?

Will the view’s listeners unsubscribe from the DOM events automatically when the view is removed or should they be unsubscribed manually?

Comment: In the first scenario, the event listeners are removed. The work is done by jQuery's .remove() method (https://api.jquery.com/remove/), which Backbone.View.prototype.remove delegates to. In the second scenario, your view must explicitly call .off() on the arbitrary DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a view has an events object that contains a list of events on the child nodes of the view’s $el that are being listened to;

These will be undelegated (removed) by backbone when view is removed properly using it's remove method.

> a view listens to some arbitrary DOM elements, not necessarily children of the view’s `$el`. is this situation any different from the previous one?

There is no built in way of doing this using backbone, and is not recommended. If you do this by yourself - Some element holding event listeners pointing to methods on your view which backbone is not aware of - You have to clean these up yourself else  it'll create zombie views (memory leaks)